# Is Joda DateTime supported by Hibernate 6?

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime, hibernate-6.x

I am trying to upgrade my spring boot from 2.7.X to 3.2.X. But the following code is not compiling.

```
@jakarta.persistence.Entity
public class Order {
... 
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")//can't resolve method type
private DateTime createdOn;

}
```

Is Joda `DateTime` supported by Hibernate 6.4.X? If yes, how to migrate the above code?

Comment: Any reason why you still use Joda DateTime? The homepage (https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) says: "Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java **prior to Java SE 8**. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310)." When upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.x you necessarily must upgrade to Java 17 which is many versions later than Java SE 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## java.time

Given below is a notice on the home page of Joda-Time:

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this
> project.**

The [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html), `java.time` was released as part of Java 8 in March 2024 (**ten years ago**). Since then, it is highly recommended to switch to the `java.time` API from both, the legacy `java.util` API as well as the Joda-Time API.

I recommend you change your code to `java.time` API as follow:

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.ZonedDateTimeType")
private java.time.ZonedDateTime createdOn;
```

Given below is the [Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8/5.6.15.Final) for it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Remove all Maven dependencies of Joda-Time and Jadira.

[Here](https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html) is an article written by the creator of Joda-Time and architect of `java.time` API.

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**